# Erro no AndroidManifest em android:theme

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou iniciando no desenvolvimento de android, faço os passos para cria um app e testar mas sempre no final de qualquer projeto fica a uma mensagem de erro em android:theme, vou postar abaixo a tela espero que alguém possa ajudar, obrigado.

[image: Tela com erro no AndroidManifest]

Comment: Acredito que o seu problema é a ausência de arquivo de _styles_ . Tente criar dentro de _Values_ um arquivo chamado styles.xml  e definir as configurações do AppTheme.

Comment: Depois de criar esse arquivo quais configurações coloco nele?

Comment: Lembrei-me de que esse arquivo é criado automaticamente pelo eclipse. Mas, segue aqui o [link](http://goo.gl/iBPs6k) para o _styles default_. Caso isso resolva, avise-me para postar uma resposta.

Comment: Não funcionou, agora fica mostrando uma mensagem de erro no styles.

Comment: O nome do arquivo que você criou, está no plural? (_styles.xml_) E você lembrou de ajustar no seu código para o nome correto do arquivo ?

Comment: Está no plural e com o nome correto.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19507/discussion-between-emanuelsn-and-thiago).

Comment: Não tem nada a ver com a sua pergunta, mais como vc tá iniciando o Google já fornece o sdk da jetbrains o Android Studio, tente usar ele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você simplesmente não possui um arquivo de estilos com o tema **AppTheme** declarado

Crie, dentro da pasta **values**, um arquivo chamado **styles**.xml.

Cole esse conteúdo nele.

(O nome do arquivo é arbitrário, ou seja, tanto faz... você escolhe )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
</style>
```

O tema acima é o mais simples possível.

Se quiser aprender a fazer temas mais atuais, usando o Material Design por exemplo, pesquise sobre a biblioteca de compatibilidade versão 7 (appcompat7)

Com ela, seu tema ficaria assim (com design de lollipop)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```